# How to get startup project with VsShellUtilities API?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

With [`VsShellUtilities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsshellutilities.aspx) API, I can get the project for a particular file with the `GetProject` method. How can I get the startup project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the startup project(s) of a solution you can use:

- The [IVsSolutionBuildManager.get_StartupProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager.get_startupproject.aspx) method, but only if you know in advance that your solution has only a single startup project.
- The automation model (EnvDTE). You can get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE ([HOWTO: Get the EnvDTE.DTE instance from a package](https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/DtePackage)) and then use [DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionbuild.startupprojects.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the first from C#?

Comment: Yes, why not? Use IVsSolutionBuildManager solutionBuildManager = base.GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager)) as IVsSolutionBuildManager;